# Combining polymorphic association with many-to-many association... is this setup right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, polymorphism

I have a Genre model, and I want both videos to have many genres and profiles to have many genres. I also want genres to have many videos and genres to have many profiles. I understand the polymorphic and join table stuff, so I'm wondering if my code below will work as I intend it to. Also, I'd appreciate any advice on how to access things in my controller and views.

This is what I envision that the join table should look like (I don't think I need an elaborate `:has :through` association because all I need in the join table are the associations and nothing else, so the table won't have a model):

```
genres_videos_profiles:
-----------------------------------------------------
id | genre_id | genre_element_id | genre_element_type
```

Here's my genre.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :genre_element, :polymorphic => true
```

Here's video.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :genres, :as => :genre_element
```

Here's profile.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :genres, :as => :genre_element
```

Will this work as I intend it to? I'd like some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know HABTM associations can´t be polymorphic, I couldn´t find an example like yours in the API documentation. If you want only join tables, your code could look like this:

```
class Genre
  has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
end

class Video
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end

class Profile
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end
```

And access it like Mike already wrote:

```
@genre.profiles
@profile.genres
@genre.videos
@video.genres
```

Migrations (for join tables only):

```
class CreateGenresVideosJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :genres_videos, {:id => false, :force => true} do |t|
      t.integer :genre_id
      t.integer :video_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :genres_videos
  end
end

class CreateGenresProfilesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :genres_profiles, {:id => false, :force => true} do |t|
      t.integer :genre_id
      t.integer :profile_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :genres_profiles
  end
end
```

Comment: hmm... what would the table columns consist of?

Comment: ahh ok, so you're splitting them up so you don't have to deal with polymorphism... this seems like the easiest solution, i like it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that has_and_belongs_to_many can be a bit difficult to follow when it comes to polymorphic (if it even works). So if you want to do the polymorhpic thing, then you can't use any "through" syntax:

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genres_videos_profiles
end

class GenresVideosProfile
  belongs_to :genre
  belongs_to :genre_element, :polymorphic => true

  scope :videos, where(:genre_element_type => "Video")
  scope :profiles, where(:genre_element_type => "Profile")
end
```

And then you use it like:

```
# All genre elements
@genre.genres_videos_profiles.each do |gvp|
  puts gvp.genre_element.inspect
end

# Only video genre elements
@genre.genres_videos_profiles.videos.each do |gvp|
  puts gvp.genre_element.inspect
end
```

Comment: nice solution... so GenresVideosProfiles has `genre_id` `genre_element_type` and `genre_element_id`... is that right?

Comment: That is correct. The pros with this scenario is of course that you can easily use the same setup if you want to add genres to an additional model. However, if you know that it will only be videos and profiles then I might go with something like auralbee posted.

Comment: yeah, your solution is elegant but since only videos and profiles will have genres, I might as well go with auralbee's answer, especially since I'm not too familiar with polymorphism and it would add some complexity to my controllers... thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Check out that: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/3/polymorphic-through

For me it was perfect and clean!